# CMake Function "not declared in this scope" Error

Tags: cmake, googletest

I am brand new to CMake and have been reading through blogs to get this to work.  I had a cmake file working when all the files were in the same directory but can't seem to get this to work - the include dir was giving me trouble. In this last attempted I was referencing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56462415/cmake-error-cannot-determine-link-language-for-target) stack overflow thread.  This was the closest I came to getting this to work.  Please help.

**File Tree**

```
$ tree
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── include
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   └── math.h
├── src
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   └── math.c
└── testy
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    └── math.cpp

3 directories, 7 files
```

**CMake Files**

```
$ more CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
project(iamtesting)
enable_testing()
add_subdirectory(include)
add_subdirectory(src)
add_subdirectory(testy)
```

```
$ more include/CMakeLists.txt
add_library(include INTERFACE)
target_include_directories(include INTERFACE ./)
```

```
$ more src/CMakeLists.txt
add_library(src STATIC math.c)
target_include_directories(src PUBLIC ./)
```

```
$ more testy/CMakeLists.txt
set(TEST_EXE_NAME math)
add_executable(${TEST_EXE_NAME} math.cpp)
target_include_directories(${TEST_EXE_NAME} PUBLIC ./)
target_link_libraries(${TEST_EXE_NAME} src)
add_test(NAME "testDatabase" COMMAND ${TEST_EXE_NAME})
```

**CMake**

```
$ cmake CMakeLists.txt
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 7.5.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 7.5.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/jason/gtest
```

**Make**

```
$ make
Scanning dependencies of target src
[ 25%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/src.dir/math.c.o
/home/jason/gtest/src/math.c: In function ‘main’:
/home/jason/gtest/src/math.c:5:24: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘sum’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   printf("10+20=%d\n", sum(10,20));
                        ^~~
[ 50%] Linking C static library libsrc.a
[ 50%] Built target src
Scanning dependencies of target math
[ 75%] Building CXX object testy/CMakeFiles/math.dir/math.cpp.o
In file included from /usr/include/gtest/gtest.h:1874:0,
                 from /home/jason/gtest/testy/math.cpp:1:
/home/jason/gtest/testy/math.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void widget_ok_Test::TestBody()’:
/home/jason/gtest/testy/math.cpp:5:13: error: ‘sum’ was not declared in this scope
   ASSERT_EQ(sum(1, 1), 2);
             ^
/home/jason/gtest/testy/math.cpp:5:3: error: template argument 1 is invalid
   ASSERT_EQ(sum(1, 1), 2);
   ^
testy/CMakeFiles/math.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'testy/CMakeFiles/math.dir/math.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [testy/CMakeFiles/math.dir/math.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:158: recipe for target 'testy/CMakeFiles/math.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [testy/CMakeFiles/math.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:94: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

**Src Files**

```
$ more src/math.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "math.h"

int main() {
  printf("10+20=%d\n", sum(10,20));
  return 0;
}

int sum(int x, int y) {
    return x + y;
}
```

```
$ more include/math.h
#define _MATH_H_

int sum(int, int);
```

```
$ more src/math.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "math.h"

int main() {
  printf("10+20=%d\n", sum(10,20));
  return 0;
}

int sum(int x, int y) {
    return x + y;
}
```

```
$ more testy/math.cpp
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "math.h"

TEST(widget, ok) {
  ASSERT_EQ(sum(1, 1), 2);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

Comment: It looks like your `#include "math.h"` directive actually includes **standard C header** [math.h](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man0/math.h.0p.html), not your header `include/math.h`. It is better to NOT name your own headers as the standard ones. Moreover, your header is simply not accessible from the `src` and `math` executables, since you don't link `include` library which provides path your `math.h` header.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few issues with your setup:

1. `libInclude` (defined in `include/CMakeLists.txt`) is not needed. You need to create one lib, `libSrc`, that has `include` directory added via `target_include_directories`.
2. `src` folder shall not be added via `target_include_directories` as it only stores source files which are implementation of your functionality and shall never be actually used as `#include`s anywhere.
3. there shall be only one `main` function in every program, so most probably you shall remove `main` from `src/math.c`. You should have one `main.cpp` for your executable that will link `libSrc` and one `main` method for your tests (`math.cpp` in your case, you're linking the `libSrc` correctly there)
4. `include/math.h` shall have proper [include guard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard)